# How to accept values into array using Textbox and display the Sum of numbers using a Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, arrays, button

I have three TextBoxes and a Button. I should be able to enter multiple numbers on the TextBoxes. When I click on the Button, the sum of the numbers should be displayed on another TextBox. **How to accept values into array using Textbox and display the Sum of numbers using a Button?**

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
 int[] numbers = new int[2];  // Declare the array 

 public void Button1_Click() {
    numbers[0] = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    numbers[1] = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    numbers[2] = Int32.Parse(TextBox3.Text);

    TextBox4.Text = numbers.Sum().ToString();
 }
```

Note: You probably want to add some error handling into the application to ensure that the textbox values are indeed numbers.  Also use `TryParse` rather than the standard `Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some separatefor example comma, then split your Textbox value to get string array, then you can try parse string to int or decimal.Then calculate sum